# Form in same line inside a modal

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small login form which I want in a same line. 
First I tried to use it with labels but it did not work as I expected. So I ditched the labels and used placeholders instead for the inputs. But now I get what I want but its not in proper form.

This is how it looks:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm ?</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure you want to continue ?
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="doAuthenticate" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <div ng-show="doAuthenticate">
        <hr>
        <form name="authForm" ng-submit="authenticate(authForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="col-sm-2" type="text" ng-model="authUser" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                <input class="col-sm-2" type="password" ng-model="authPass" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="authForm.$invalid">Authenticate!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I actually use Angular in my code. I just want to know how to get the login form appear in a single line all neatly aligned. I also want it to be responsive. Like when I resize, I want the inputs to appear one below the other along with the button.

EDIT: This is how it looks after the modification:

[image: image2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be this will help . 
You should have to use bootstrap classes for proper alignment.
best way is your html should be correct so as to html should display as you want.

try your self. this is suggestion

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm ?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
          Are you sure you want to continue ?
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" alight="right">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="doAuthenticate" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="row">
            
          
          <div ng-show="doAuthenticate " class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <hr>
            <form name="authForm" ng-submit="authenticate(authForm.$valid)" novalidate>
              <div class="form-group">
               <table class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <tr>
<td>
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="authUser" placeholder="Username"  required autofocus>
               
</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>
 <input class="form-control"  type="password" ng-model="authPass" placeholder="Password" required>
</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="authForm.$invalid">Authenticate!</button></td>
</tr>
              </table>
 
                
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I only need the change for the form. The rest of the modal is fine. That is how I want it actually. I just want the 'modal-footer' to be in the right form. Your solution looks good, but the input boxes are not with round edges.

Comment: now have a look on code by adding form-control class to input the boxes are with rounded edges

Comment: This works. But it is not responsive. I have attached the screenshot of how it looks.

Comment: you have to adjust width of input type the it will responsive.

Comment: Yes it works great. But there is only one small change. I need a little bit of space between the input fields. Right now they appear together. Just that little change and your answer will become perfect.

Comment: @ViChU the stackoverflow community doesn't provide issue fix services members here providing you with just a little help to get you started, it doesn't mean they will fix your problem completely, thanks

Comment: Agree with you @SagarGuhe

Comment: @ViChU you can add &nbsp; to add more space between input or you can apply css .

for your help till i am editing the code lets have a look on it Thanks

Comment: I have change the code by adding empty td element in code please have a look on it

Comment: @SagarGuhe I know that. I tried adding &nbsp but it did not work correctly. That's why I asked for his help.

Comment: @Rahul I am asking you for help since you provided me a proper solution. If you can't help me out, please don't proceed any further with editing you solution.

Comment: no no it's my pleasure to help i think i almost change the code for your help

Comment: @Rahul And also, before I accept your answer, I need to make sure that your solution solves my problem. So that it will be helpful for other people with the same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/jL5pj1nq/) that illustrates the behavior you wanted.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm ?</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure you want to continue ?
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div ng-show="doAuthenticate">
        <form name="authForm" ng-submit="authenticate(authForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="authUser" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="col-sm-3 form-control" type="password" ng-model="authPass" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="authForm.$invalid">Authenticate!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="doAuthenticate" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```